# The following from address failed on amazon linux ec-2 server with joomla 2.5.14

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, joomla

I have a form on joomla 2.5.14 submitting to an email address but when I try I get the following system error 'the following from address failed: email@email.com'.

The site is hosted on amazon ec-2 using amazons linux.  The mx settings are correct and mail is being delivered to the address from other sources.

I believe there is something ont he server blocking the email from being sent but I do not know what or how to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon has many restrictions on what you can do with SMTP email over EC2. Your best bet is to use their SES service to send email. It's cheap and you don't need to maintain your email server.

Comment: Thanks i thought that service would be difficult to set up so I wanted to try the way i was somewhat familiar with.  Ses was very easy to set up and its working great thanks